# Only allow signed_in user to comment in the post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Currently, I am using devise gem, I want only a signed_in user to comments in the post and display the flash message like "you must log_in to comment for the post" for the not sign_in user if they comment in the post.

This is my comments_controller.rb file

```
  class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :correct_user, only: :destroy

  def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:name, :body))
      @comment.user_id = current_user.id
      @comment.save


      redirect_to post_path(@post)      
  end

  def destroy
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
      @comment.destroy

      redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
  end

  def correct_user
    @comment = current_user.comments.find_by(id: params[:id])
    if @comment.nil?
      flash[:alert] = "Not your comment!"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

end
```

Below is my _comment.html.erb file under views/comments folder

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
<div class="comment_content">
    <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
    <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>
    <p class="comment_time"><%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> Ago</p>
</div>

<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.post, comment],
                                  method: :delete,
                                  class: "button",
                                    data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </p>
<% end -%>
```

and my comment model

```
  class Comment < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :post
   belongs_to :user
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your new or create action you can use. You can also make it as a before_action filter

```
    unless user_signed_in?
      flash[:notice] = "you must log_in to comment for the post"
      redirect_to #your login page
    end
```

Spend some time going through documentation http://github.com/plataformatec/devise